# Killing PPID can kill all child process association with it at same time?

Tags: shell, unix, ksh, aix

I have tried to kill PPID process which terminate process (also kills child pid's) immediately sends signal back in seconds to one of my console, but child process are taking time to respond back termination response.  Any one has any idea why it is happening..?

Comment: What signal is sent back to the console?  Was the parent process started from the shell/console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever the parent process gets killed, the child processes become ***ORPHAN processes*** so the INIT process becomes the parent of the ORPHAN processes. As ***INIT process*** is created in such a way that whenever any process gets killed all of it's children are taken care by the INIT process until the processes finish.

Comment: I think I should wait some more time to get best out of before I mark it answer..

Comment: Whenever a process gets killed it's child processes do not die immediately. You can google about INIT process and you will find that whenever any process gets killed then it's children are taken care by the INIT process. As it is the responsibility of the INIT process to take care of such processes.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the parent process did not catch any signals, while the child processes did.

Alternatively, the child processes had resources open and are attempting a *graceful exit*, making sure  those resources are properly taken care of.

In this case you may need to rewrite the parent process to *catch* the signal, forward it to its children, and then `wait()` for them to finish, and exit.

Comment: Thanks Henk, I have already implemented solution by killing from bottom level child process first then proceed last parent ID. My question is why it was happening like that make sense with Mayank answer.